# How to use gsub to remove . at the end of the string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, substring, gsub

I need to remove all the special characters from the end of the string that sometimes will be there and sometimes not.

I have written this `.gsub(/[,()'"]./,'')` but it does not remove the `.` (full stop) from the string.

Can you tell me what is wrong in this?

Comment: Did you mean to write `.gsub(/[,()'".]/,'')`? With the dot inside the character class? The end of string can be specified with `\z`. Try ``.gsub(/[,()'".]+\z/,'')`` to remove 1 or more chars in the character class at the end of the string. A couple of example strings with expected output would help.

Comment: thanks, it worked just the way I needed it.

Comment: More tags are not better than fewer tags. You should include only those that readers are likely to search on or to exclude from searches. On that basis I suggest you remove "string", "substring" and "gsub". It's not a Rails question so "ruby-on-rails" should be removed. One you are missing is "regex". I therefore suggest your tags be "ruby" and "regex".  Also, Ruby does not provide a definition for "special characters", so you should define the term in your question (or just list the chargers without giving them a name). They might be inferred from your regex, but it's best to be explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
.gsub(/[,()'".]+\z/,'')
```

The dot must be put inside the character class, the negated character class must be quantified with `+` (1 or more occurrences) and the `\z` anchor should be added to assert the position at the end of the string.

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/yRtkIA95VVZkpt).

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be `.gsub`?

[String#delete_suffix](https://devdocs.io/ruby~2.5/string#method-i-delete_suffix) may be simpler.

`my_string.delete_suffix '.'`

Comment: yes because the string can contain `, . " ' /` at the end.

Comment: Updated answer. delete_suffix is what you want.

Comment: That only removes one trailing `.` – what about `'`, `"`, `/` and `,` or multiple occurrences?

Comment: @Stefan: The OP is asking two different questions, 1) how to remove `.` at the end of the string, and 2) how to remove special characters at the end of the string. This answer is answering the former question. IMO, questions that ask two different question shouldn't be answered but instead closed as "unclear what you are asking", but this answer is at least a valid answer to the first question asked by the OP.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the OP wants to remove certain special characters. The regexp almost works, it removes all but the `.`, hence the question's title.